# Зависимость (размер массива - время исполнения алгоритма) для TimSort даёт непонятные результаты

Tags: сортировка, график

график зависимости времени, поделенного на nlog_2_n от размера массива
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
график на большем количестве элементов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Реализовал свой TimSort на java. Алгоритм работает верно. [image: График зависимости времени работы от размера входного массива]Не совсем понимаю, что это за "подпрыгивания" времени исполнения алгоритма в произвольные моменты времени. Те, которые совсем высоко прыгают, можно списать на распределение ресурсов процессора на другие программы, запущенные на ПК в это время, но те, которые прыгают совсем рядом с графиком, выглядят как-будто бы намеренными, потому что сделав еще 3 графика, я увидел что ситуация более менее повторяется. К чему это можно отнести? Также хотелось бы узнать как проверить, что этот график действительно n * logn, а не n^2 допустим? выглядит вообще как прямая

Comment: Как готовятся данные для каждого прохода? Как измеряется время? Длины до 10000 - маловато.

Comment: @MBo переделал на 1000 файлов с числами от 1 до 1000 по 1-100000 в каждом(график прикрепил). скачки пропали. остался вопрос, как показать, что это nlogn, а не n^2?

Comment: Разделить значение времени на nlogn, должно колебаться вокруг горизонтальной прямой. У вас могут быть такие данные, что работать будет почти за линейное время.

Comment: @MBo всё-таки наверное не так, nlogn это же число операций, а время у меня в нс.

Comment: Какая разница - время в общем случае пропорционально зависит от числа операций,  `C*n*logn`

Comment: @MBo прикрепил полученный график, можно ли сказать, что это "колебается вокруг горизонтальной прямой"?

Comment: Да, стремится к горизонтали очень хорошо. Для сравнения смоделируйте квадрат - будет совсем другое